# iOS Push Notifications with Windows Azure and Unity3D

Tags: ios, azure, notifications, push-notification, unity-game-engine

I am using [Windows Azure Notifications Hub](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/notification-hubs/) to create a push notifications service for my **iOS** game made with **Unity3D**. I only want simple notifications like informing about an update or a new feature.

But I am having some issues. I am following the tutorial [Get Started with Notifications Hubs](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/?fb=fr-fr).
I did everything except the sending notification part, because I don't receive any token.

Moreover, I can't add the [Windows Azure SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/fr-fr/downloads/?sdk=mobile) into my application because I don't have any AppDelegate.h or AppDelegate.m in the XCode project generated by Unity3D.
When I call in Unity3D [RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/NotificationServices.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes.html) I don't receive any token back. And I think it's the first main problem.

I don't know where the issue comes from. Should I use another service ? How can I solve the issue as I don't know where does it comes from ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for push notification permissions make sure that you haven't accidentally denied this permission at some point as iOS will only show this option **once**.

You can check and see the status of push notification permissions in the Settings menu of your iPhone/iPad.

If you are willing to spend a little money you can get the etcetera plugin from [prime31](http://prime31.com/docs#iosEtc)
that can help you get a token and also provides access to other native APIs.

Regarding the lack of a **AppDelegate.h** file from the XCode project, this is because Unity doesn't generate 2 files: one for the app delegate and one for the controller, they are in the same file called **UnityAppController.h/m**.

Note: is not trivial to add cocoa touch controls using this class if this is what you want.